# How does one get initial centroids as vectors for mahout kmeans?

Tags: input, cluster-analysis, mahout

One of the switches for mahout's implementation of kmeans is -c (clusters).

"The input centroids, as Vectors. Must be a SequenceFile of Writable, Cluster/Canopy."

I don't know how I'm supposed to make these centroids though. I have already converted my text data to sequenceFiles and from there into Vectors. I just need to figure this out and I can try and cluster the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RandomSeedGenerator](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/clustering/kmeans/RandomSeedGenerator.html) class to generate random initial centroids for k-means clustering.

```
Path centroids = RandomSeedGenerator.buildRandom(conf,new Path("testdata2/points.seq"),new Path("testdata2/clusters"),k,new EuclideanDistanceMeasure());
```

Just provide path to you data points(points.seq) that you want to cluster and path for intial centroids (testdata2/clusters)

If it successfully run you would have file part-randomSeed file under the directory testdata2/clusters.

Comment: Right, sounds good. I'm doing this mostly by command line in Ubuntu. 

Having read more into this over the last couple of days, it looks like by specifying a directory and the -k switch, it's supposed to use RandomSeedGenerator automatically. I think something is wrong with my data. 

Here is an example of the command I used:

`sudo /opt/mahout/bin/mahout kmeans -i /INPUT_DIR/tfidf-vectors/ -o /OUTPUT_DIR/allNYC_DataClusters -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.EuclideanDistanceMeasure -c /home/efx/Desktop/allNYC_initialKClusters -k 50 -x 50 -cl`

Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use random initial centroids with a set number of clusters (which is a very common approach), you don't have to create initial centroids before clusterizing at all.

Citing from the [Mahout k-means article](http://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/k-means-clustering.html):

> Note: if the -k argument is supplied, any clusters in the -c directory will be overwritten and -k random points will be sampled from the input vectors to become the initial cluster centers.

Thus the initial centroids directory just has to exist and can be empty - it will be filled with k randomly chosen centroids before running the actual clustering.

Following I provide a command linen call which I just successfully ran. I prefer to use the more verbal parameters, thus I use `--clusters` instead of the equivalent `-c` to define the (empty) directory for the initial centroids and `--numClusters` instead of the equivalent `-k` to define that I want 3 clusters in total (resulting in 3 initial centroids).

```
mahout kmeans \
--input output/seq2sparse/001/tfidf-vectors \
--output output/kmeans/001 \
--clusters output/initial_centroids/001 \
--numClusters 3 \
--distanceMeasure org.apache.mahout.common.distance.CosineDistanceMeasure \
--maxIter 20 \
--method mapreduce
```

Comment: I get this error when i run the command `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No input clusters found in initial-clusters/001/part-randomSeed. Check your -c argument.`

Comment: @AbhyudayaSrinet how did you get around this?